# How to pass a value of a column as a parameter from another column in displaytag using struts2

Tags: struts2, displaytag

In the below code, I am trying to pass 2 parameters from `<display:column>` tag. I have to pass `code` and `level` properties to an action(as shown below). I am not able to pass value of another column as parameter from a column. Here I am not getting value of `level` property in `code` property.

```
<s:form action="levelHierarchy">
        <display:table id="searchList" name="searchList" pagesize="8"
            export="false" requestURI="/getComponentDetails" sort="list">
            <display:column property="code" title="Code" sortable="true" paramId="levelId"  href="levelHierarchy.action?level=${searchList.level}"></display:column>
            <display:column property="description" title="Description" sortable="true" />
            <display:column property="level" title="Level" sortable="true" />
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
        </display:table>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the form you don't have any fields to submit. You should define at least [hidden](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/hidden.html) fields to the columns that contains the values you want to pass to the action. You also need the use of `uid` attribute of the `<display:table` tag to access the row values.

```
<display:table uid="row" id="searchList" name="searchList" pagesize="8" export="false" requestURI="/getComponentDetails" sort="list" >
  <display:column property="code" title="Code" sortable="true" paramId="levelId"  href="levelHierarchy.action?level=${searchList.level}">
    <s:hidden name="submitList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}]" value="%{#attr.row.code}"/>
  </display:column>
  <%-- Other columns like that --%>
</display:table>
```

in the action you should create the property placeholder for the submitted values.